# How does an inverting op amp work?

Tags: operational-amplifier

What I do know is that because the current throughout the circuit is constant, and the resistances differ, the voltage input and voltage output are different for an operational amplifier. Also, the gain is dependent on the resistor values. However, how are the current values constant if there is an op amp in their path through the circuit?

Comment: Because op amps have very low input leakage.

Comment: And because of the "virtual ground" principle: Negative feedback causes an equilibrium state which results in a voltage at the inverting opamp input that is very close to ground (in practice: Vout/Aol with Aol=open-loop gain).

Comment: (1) There is no such thing as an 'inverting opamp'. There are inverting opamp *circuits.* (2) The current throughout a circuit is only constant in a passive resistive circuit. In any circuit with reactive or active components it isn't constant at all. Otherwise the reactive or active components couldn't have any effect.

Comment: @EJP: (1)In case your remark is a response to my comment: The opamp has two inputs. And I spoke about the "inverting opamp input".(2) I suppose, using the term "constant" the questioner means: "equal" (The same current through two resistors).

Comment: LvW, you're right about my use of "constant." EJP, that's a funny situation I wasn't thinking about. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @LvW (a) The title of the post refers to 'an inverting opamp'. (b) I don't engage in speculation. I am commenting on the words he posted. In both cases, if it isn't what he meant, let him fix it.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to say or if I'm understanding you correctly, but I am female. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a homework question.

Remember your ideal op-amp characteristics (cribbed from hyperphysics):

Infinite voltage gain

Infinite input impedance

Zero output impedance

Infinite bandwidth

Zero input offset voltage (i.e., exactly zero out if zero in).

Looking at the circuit you want to understand, imagine applying some voltage to the input. How does that change the voltage at the inverting pin? Given infinite gain and input impedance, how would the output change (The output is simply [Gain * (in+ - in-)])? How would this output then feed back to the non-inverting pin? If it overshoots the voltage at the inverting pin, maybe there is some voltage where (in+ - in-) == 0 and then the output would be stable.

Comment: Hi Dave, it was not a homework question. Still, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It might help someone else if they have it as a HW question, though.

Answer (score 0):

The opamp draws no current at its inputs, but its output sinks the current that flows from the source and through both resistors. In the inverting amplifier configuration the opamp drives its output in the opposite direction to the input until the voltage on the - input equals the voltage on the + input.

Since the same current is flowing though both resistors, the output voltage (relative to the + input) will be equal to the input voltage multiplied by the ratio between the two resistors, but inverted (positive input voltage = negative output voltage).

Comment: Pedantically, the op-amp draws *a functionally irrelevant* current at it's inputs. There *is* input bias current, and in certain obscure applications it can actually be an issue, but it's *generally* not a problem.